# PHP Shell_exec for certain commands only

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

Is there a way to disable [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) with exception of only certain commands that can be whitelisted?

I figured I could always go in and just put those commands into `mod_sec`, the major commands that I don't want run. But that kind of config is not enough. I want to disable `shell_exec` but allow `shell_exec` to run with certain commands only, two to be exact.

I am running CentOS, Cpanel and PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: The system administrator (root) can normally configure the commands available in a user's shell. PHP will create the shell with the user it runs under, so I don't see any reason why this should not be possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you only want to allow 2 specific commands, why not hard code them and abstract the mechanism for calling them so that you are not passing the user input directly to `shell_exec()`? CentOS, cpanel and PHP 5.2.17 smells like an old-ish WHM install, which can be difficult to configure for stuff like this and unless you are the server admin you won't be able to do it yourself.

Comment: Also the HTTPD context of SE Linux might be of use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinux

Comment: I have not tried anything so far but `disable_functions` in php.ini. That's why I was wondering if it was even possible to enable only certain commands through as a whole for the entire server. I am root, oldish WHM install no, PHP is just kind of old since 5.3 still has bugs we haven't upgraded it yet. But WHM and Apache are both latest. I have searched high and low on Google without any success in finding anything.

Comment: No, `disable_functions` is about PHP functions, not the ones you can access *via* `shell_exec`. Those commands are under the control of the operating system (or more precisely the shell environment that will be created). I'm not aware that a ready-made solution exists you could extend PHP with so that such a feature would be configurable from within PHP.

Comment: Well `disabled_functions` allows us to disable the use of that function from within PHP scripts. Which is what we want, but we want to be able to allow only two commands in, so it works to disable, we just can't allow the other commands in through it. The only thing I could think of was recompile PHP from source and edit that part for `disable_functions` to add a new param for enable of some sort. But that would require a lot of work that I didn't know if there was another way.

Comment: If we go about it the other way of system side that's fine, but since the users have access with FTP to their user dir they could change the allowed commands themselves. Unless there is another way to allow and disable commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a dissable/whitelist per se, but if done correctly it gives users supervised and strictly controlled access to only those shell commands that you specify in your code.

```
    $Ops = array(
            'function1'  => function($parameter){ 
                    DO PARAMETER CHECK HERE; 
                    shell_exec("CommandThatIsSafetoPerform" + parameter here);
                },
            'function2'  => function($parameter){ 
                    DO PARAMETER CHECK HERE; 
                    shell_exec("CommandThatIsSafetoPerform" + parameter here);
                },
            'function3'  => function($parameter){ 
                    DO PARAMETER CHECK HERE; 
                    shell_exec("CommandThatIsSafetoPerform" + parameter here);
                },

    );
```

then call use something like this:

```
call_user_func(Ops["function1"], "your parameter here");
```

A few special notes: Giving users access to the parameters is asking for trouble. You are better off hard coding EVERYTHING and not giving users the ability to modifiy any of the parameters.